# Detecting if a site is refreshed on a mobile phone

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, django-views

I developed this js code, that should detect when a site is loaded for the first time or is refreshed. I send this information tho a django view.
The problem is that it works on PC but not on mobile devices like phones, tablets, etc...
Here is the javascript code:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
            // Check if the page has been reloaded
            var isReloaded = sessionStorage.getItem('isReloaded');

            if (!isReloaded) {
                // It's the first visit or a new session
                sessionStorage.setItem('isReloaded', 'true');
                // Perform actions for the first visit here
                
            }

            // Send the reload information to the server
            var isRefreshed = isReloaded ? 'true' : 'false';
            var csrfToken = '{{ csrf_token }}'; 
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '',
                data: {
                    'is_refreshed': isRefreshed,
                    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}' // Include CSRF token for security
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    // Handle the response from the server here, if needed
                    console.log(data.message);
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                    // Handle errors here, if needed
                    console.error(error);
                }
            });// Replace with your CSRF token
            // Make an AJAX request here to send 'isRefreshed' and 'csrfToken' to the server.
        });
```

Comment: Your webpage might be served from the browser's cache, and therefore not call the load event handler. You need a hard refresh to reload the page completely and fire the load event. You could say that if the load event doesn't fire that the page is not refreshed, so your code does work. Alternatively you could try something with [the focus event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/focus_event)?

Comment: Are you in incognito/private mode on the mobile browser by by any chance?

Comment: No, i am not using any of that browser